# How do I overload the ostream operator<< with an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, overloading, operator-keyword, ostream

I'm having trouble overloading my `operator<<` to print the contents of an array of unknown size. I searched for a solution, but the only one I found would require me to put all of my private data members in a struct (which seems a bit unnecessary to me). I can't edit the function to make it a friend or change `*q` to `&q` (or a const).

Here's my << overload code:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Quack *q)
{
    if (q->itemCount() == 0)
        out << endl << "quack: empty" << endl << endl;
    else
    {
        int i;
        int foo;
        for (int i = 0; i < q->itemCount(); i++ )
        {
            foo = (*q)[i];
            out << *(q + i);
        } // end for
        out << endl;
    }

    return out;
}
```

And here are my private data members:

```
private:
int     *items;                     // pointer to storage for the circular array.
                                    // Each item in the array is an int.
int     count;
int     maxSize;
int     front;
int     back;
```

Here is how the function is called (cannot edit this):

```
    quack = new Quack(QUACK_SIZE);
    //put a few items into the stack
    cout << quack;
```

Here is how the output should be formatted:

```
quack: 1, 2, 3, 8, 6, 7, 0
```

and if the array is empty, then

```
quack: empty
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: So, you're trying to do duck typing, eh?

Comment: If `operator <<` isn't allowed to be a friend, why bother to list the private fields of `Quack`? What public methods of `Quack` allow access to individual items or `Quack::items`, and to the item count?

Comment: @snazzy: If you can't modify `Quack`, then you need to say so in your question.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my post to add the calling function. I also remembered that there's an itemCount function in the Quack public class.

Comment: What's the problem? Your function looks okay, except that (a) you are using `q` as a `Quack` not a `Quack*`, and (b) the function _shouldn't_ take a `Quack*` anyway.

Comment: How do I print an item in the array given a pointer to an array?

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is to redirect to a member function, like this:

```
void Quack::printOn(ostream &out) const
{
    out << "quack: ";
    if(count == 0)
        out << "empty";
    else 
    {
        out << items[0];
        for ( int i = 1 ; i < count ; i++ )
        {
            out << ",  " << items[i];
        }
    }
    out << "\n";
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &out,const Quack &q)
{
    q.printOn(out);
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should make your `operator<<` take a `const Quack&`, not a `Quack*`:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Quack &q)
{
   ...
}
```

Put this in your `Quack` class definition:

```
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, const Quack &q);
```

That will allow your `operator<<` to access the private members of `q`.